# Qual a diferença do setup e data no vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Recentemente me deparei com uma propriedade nova `setup` e não estou entendendo muito bem a diferença dela para o tradicional `data` :

```
setup () {
}
```

:

```
data () {
  return {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Diferença entre `data()` e `setup()`**

`data()` é um método que é usado para definir as propriedades de dados de um componente Vue. Ele é usado para armazenar informações que serão exibidas no template do componente. O `data()` é uma função que retorna um objeto com as propriedades que serão usadas no componente. Essas propriedades podem ser usadas no template usando a sintaxe de interpolação {{}} ou diretamente na lógica do componente.

`setup()` é um método que foi introduzido recentemente no Vue 3.x, este é usado para criar lógicas de componente. Ele fornece acesso ao contexto de instância, incluindo propriedades como props, emit, refs etc. Além disso, o `setup()` também permite acesso a recursos como watch, computed, provide e inject. É uma maneira mais fácil de escrever códigos e manter a organização do seu componente.

Em resumo, o data() é usado para definir as propriedades de dados do componente e o setup() é usado para criar a lógica do componente.

**Qual dos dois é mais indicado?**

Ambos os métodos são úteis no Vue.js, e a escolha entre eles dependerá do **caso de uso específico**.

Se você precisar *apenas* de **propriedades de dados simples** para exibir no template do componente, o `data()` é uma boa escolha. Ele é simples e fácil de usar, e a sintaxe é familiar para desenvolvedores que já usaram versões anteriores do Vue.js.

Se você precisar de uma lógica de componente mais complexa, como **gerenciamento de estado, assistentes de computação, observadores de propriedades**, etc, `setup()` é a escolha mais indicada. Ele fornece acesso a **mais recursos** e permite uma escrita de código mais organizada e fácil de manter.

Em geral, se você estiver criando componentes simples que apenas exibem dados, o `data()` é uma boa escolha. Se você estiver criando componentes mais complexos com lógica avançada, o `setup()` é a escolha mais indicada.

Sei que a pergunta é antiga mas ainda acho ela relevante pra que ta iniciando no V3.x, espero ter ajudado :)

Answer (score -2):

A função setup veio com a versão 3 do Vue, ela serve como uma alternativa ao jeito de escrever um componente no Vue.

Ela não muda somente o atributo data mas toda a sua estrutura (composition API), por exemplo:

Você poderia mudar esse componente (escrito em com o jeito tradicional)

```
<script>

export default {
  name: "ComponentName",
  data() {
    return {
      propA: "",
      propB: ""
    }
  },
  methods: {
    metodoA() {
      console.log("metodoA")
    },
    metodoB() {
      console.log("metodoB")
    }
  },
  created() {
    console.log("component criado")
  }
}

</script>
```

Para algo assim:

```
<script>

import { ref } from "vue"

export default {
  name: "ComponentName",
  setup() {
    const propA = ref("")
    const propB = ref("")

    const metodoA = () => console.log("metodoA")
    const metodoB = () => console.log("metodoB")

    console.log("component criado")

    return {
      propA,
      propB,
      metodoA,
      metodoB
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

É uma sintaxe diferente e para entender melhor aconselho a ler a documentação oficial: https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#setup